# derivative of max functions in defined interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Exercise: Determine the maximum and minimum of the function $f$ over the interval $A$
$$f(x)=\max \left(1-2 x-x^{2}, 2+x-x^{2}, 1+3 x-x^{2}\right), \quad A=[-1,2]$$
My approach: Aplying  $\max\{f,g\}=\frac{f+g}{2}+\frac{|f-g|}{2}$ formula twice we get:$$f=\frac{|3 x+1|-4 x^{2}+5x+|7x-|3x+1|-1|+5}{4}$$ then I can continue by cases but it is very irritating

Is there any more advanced techniqe???

Comment: The first step should be to draw a graph of the three parabolas over that interval. You should see max and min immediately. Then try to prove that rigorously.

Answer (score 2):

hint : you need to determine the maximum on $A$ of all the different functions in the $\max()$ and then compare them to find the "greatest" maximum. Remember that you can have a maximum also at the extremes of the interval .

For the minimum instead you are right it is a bit more complicated, and that means you can't apply the same technique for the maximum but you can construct the $\max$ function dividing it in different intervals in which you use the component which is the greatest one in each interval and then you can just minimize the function defined by intervals obtained.

Comment: with maximum I agree there is fewer work to do with we can choose the greatest maximum. but what about minumum

Comment: may be I couldn't understand comprehensively. we can't choose greatest "minumum" although it works for maximum

Comment: yes, you're totally right see my edit

Comment: thank you a lot